# The @angular/compiler-cli" package was not properly installed In Cli version:1.2.1

Tags: angular

problem

> The "@angular/compiler-cli" package was not properly installed

But This Problem Doesn't Exist in Angular Cli :1.1.0.

angular version 1.2.1  package.json

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"rxjs": "^5.1.0",
"zone.js": "^0.8.4"
 },
 "devDependencies": {
"@angular/cli": "^1.2.1",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.3.2",
"@angular/language-service": "^4.0.0",
"@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
"@types/node": "~6.0.60",
"codelyzer": "~3.0.1",
"jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
"karma": "~1.7.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
"karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
"karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
"protractor": "~5.1.2",
"ts-node": "~3.0.4",
"tslint": "~5.3.2",
"typescript": "~2.3.3"
}
```

solution i tired

```
 npm uninstall -g angular-cli          # Remove global package
 npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli  # Remove from package.json

 npm uninstall -g @angular/cli         # Remove global package
 npm uninstall --save-dev @angular/cli # Remove from package.json

 rm -rf node_modules dist # Use rmdir on Windows
 npm cache clean



 npm install npm@latest -g                   #update npm
 npm install -g @angular/cli@latest          # Global package
 npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest  # Local package
 npm install @angular/compiler-cli --save-dev 
 npm install                                 # Restore removed dependencies
```

- but all of the above doesn't works for me.
- i think there may be problem in latest version.
- can anyone suggest what im lacking in latest version.

working angular 1.1.0 package.json

```
"dependencies": {
 "@angular/animations": "^4.0.0",
 "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
 "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
 "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
 "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
 "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
 "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
 "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
 "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
 "core-js": "^2.4.1",
 "json-server": "^0.10.1",
 "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
 "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
},
 "devDependencies": {
  "@angular/cli": "1.1.0",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
  "@angular/language-service": "^4.0.0",
  "@types/jasmine": "2.5.45",
  "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
  "codelyzer": "~3.0.1",
  "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
  "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
  "karma": "~1.7.0",
  "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
  "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
  "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
  "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
  "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
  "protractor": "~5.1.2",
  "ts-node": "~3.0.4",
  "tslint": "~5.3.2",
  "typescript": "~2.3.3"
 }
```

- please can anyone suggest why angular cli 1.10 works fine .

After Lot of Googling i have now fixed the problem

snapshot[image]

Comment: 1.2.6 was installed successfully yesterday (updated from 1.0.3).

Comment: remove node modules and then try

Comment: still no solution i think this is latest bug angular needs to accept

Comment: maybe you should consider removing `@angular/cli` from node_modules as well as globally after that reinstall it locally and globally?

Comment: i just need to ask then why its works angular cli version 1.1.0 ? just answer this.

Answer (score 0):

Moved these from devDependencies to dependencies section:

```
"@angular/cli": "^1.2.1",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.3.2",
```

If this still does not work than try -

1. upgrade typescript to latest ( If this step does not work tahn try
   the below step 2 )
2. And than try changing tsconfig.json to tsconfig.app.json

Comment: i simply need to ask why this problem in fresh app using angular cli i think this is bug there no problem in cli version :1.10

Comment: No , compiler-cli needs to be the part of the "dependencies" list, it means that you cannot use this npm module without it . Do try the command " npm install " once you change the location of the api to "dependencies"  section .

Comment: typescript was the problem now fixed